# move a layer to a higher z-index, actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, z-index, movieclip

I'm working with Zachary Haight's Dynamic Video Player http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/build-a-dynamic-video-player-with-actionscript-3-part-2-of-3/

and trying to add my own functionality, i added a full screen button but no matter what i do it explands out under the other items despite beingthe topmost layer (second ony to the actionscript layer

```
function fullScrnBtnClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
//add code for increasing player size
    videoBox.x = stage.stageWidth;
    videoBox.y = stage.stageHeight;
    videoBox.parent.setChildIndex( videoBox, 0);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `videoBox.parent.addChild(videoBox)`? If you want to set an object to the top most index inside its parent display list, just re-add it, or use `addChildAt`. i.e: `videoBox.parent.addChildAt(videoBox, videoBox.parent.numChildren-1)`. The latter is more verbose, but should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Index 0 is the bottom try :

```
videoBox.parent.setChildIndex( videoBox, videoBox.parent.numChildren - 1);
```

Assuming videoBox.parent is the only display object on stage, if there are others with a higher index than that they will appear above your videobox.

Comment: well i don't set the z index on anything else, so they shouldnt...
tried you change...no effect

Comment: videoBox.parent.setChildIndex( videoBox, 0); that code puts videobox under everything else in parent. Also if the videobox is the first thing added to the display list then other items that are added will be on top of it.

Comment: http://i182.photobucket.com/albums/x202/NekoLLX/flashstage.jpg that's what my stage looks like, the Player is the entire video player so its on the top most layer save Action script

Comment: looked over the AS near as i can tell nothing is added to the display list dynamiclly, all it really does is change the internal content of the various movie clip container so i cant see why anything is loading on top of it programically either